# genymotion virtual device missing IP

Tags: genymotion

everytime i try to start my virtual device in Genymotion, i get the error that there is no IP for the device i'm trying to start. I opened the Oracle VMBox, set an IP but it still gives me the same error.

I'm using windows 10, the Genymotion version is 2.6.0, and the device i'm trying to start is Nexus 5 5.1.0 android, and my Oracle VMBox version is Version 5.0.20 r106931.

[image: The Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to bother you 4Jean.

Installing Windows 10 Fall Update fixed it for me, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Open Oracle VM VirtualBox:

1. Click **Settings** >> **System**
   Now set Base memory to **1024MB** from motherboard tab. Click OK.

[image]

To solve IP address conflict,

2. Goto **File** >> **Preferences** >> **Network**
   select **Host-only Networks** tab.

[image]

If you don’t have any adapter defined, Genymotion will create it when you try to start the virtual machine.

If you have an adapter,

3. Click on **Edit** icon then a new window will be open. In the Adapter tab, set:

**IPv4 Address:** 192.168.56.1 and

**IPv4 Network Mask:** 255.255.255.0

[image]

4. Now select DHCP server. Ensure “ **Enable Server** ” is checked. Set the following configuration:

**Server Address :** 192.168.56.100

**Server Mask:** 255.255.255.0

**Lower Address Bound:**  192.168.56.101

**Upper Address Bound :** 192.168.56.254

[image]

Click OK.
Now start your Virtual Device.

http://androidcodex.net/unable-to-start-the-virtual-device-genymotion/

**CHECK**

Ensure that just one virtual adapter is enabled in **Network Connections** : 
Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections

- Right click mouse > properties or double click on your enabled **VirtualBox Host-Only Network** adapter in Network Connections

[image]

- Enable the Checkbox for **VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver**
- Click Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPV4) then click properties button

[image]

- Tick **Use the following IP address**

IP address: 192.168.56.1

Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

Leave other fields blank

[image]

Click OK and start genymotion as administrator

- If  problem persists try close genymotion, Android studio and
  Force kill adb.exe with task manager and any VirtualBox processes.

Start Genymotion as admin

- If still fails,  Go to your virtualbox settings, under the general tab on the top left , set **Type**  to **Microsoft Windows** and set Version to **windows 10**

Start Genymotion again as administrator

- Finally if still missing IP,

You may need to change IPV4 address in File > preferences > Network from 192.168.56.1 to 192.168.1.201 or run genymotion in compatibility mode (Windows 8)
Right click genymotion >properties > Compatibility >Tick **Run this program in Compatibility mode for** > Select **Windows 8** in dropdown

**PROBLEM WITH VIRTUAL NETWORK ADAPTER**

It could be that OracleVirtualBox did not install driver correctly as I experienced too.

Solution:

1. Delete all previous virtual box adapters
2. Go to device manager and click "Action" > "Add legacy hardware"
3. Install the oracle virtual box adapters manually (my path was C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\network\netadp\VBoxNetAdp.inf

After manually installing the driver 
Configure VirtualBox Network Settings

Start Oracle VM VirtualBox and go to "File" > "Preferences" > "Network" > "Host-only Network" and configure as above

Click OK and start Genymotion

Comment: I'm also using genymotion 2.6 and nexus 5 but on win 7, I have updated the answer. - CHECK

Comment: It could be a problem with your adapter

Comment: I experienced this too a long time ago. I will update answer

Comment: Updated answer once again,  hope it helps